# mousewheel outside the jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, mousewheel

I have this jscrollpane: 
http://www.complexproduction.com/aladdin/work/TOTALBANKEN
my client insists that he wants the mousewheel work even if the mouse is outside the pane.
any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: and then how can I possibly center the content?

Comment: center within an internal container... basic css

Comment: @charlietfl is there any example available?

Comment: I made it. your suggestion is very good and decent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try to use a [library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_events_mousewheelhandler.js.html) that handles mousewheel events for the whole page.

Comment: @ kinakuta I don't know how to use it. ;) anyway, this is the first time I know about Closure Tools. it looks fun!

Comment: You'll notice a demo and a source link on that page that should help you figure it out. I haven't used it myself, so the best I can offer now is just pointing at the resource.